# PCL SHOTEstimation disable warning

Tags: c++, pcl

I'm working with the Point Cloud Library (PCL) in C++ and I have multiple warning printing.

Is there a way to disable the warnings from `pcl::SHOTEstimation::computeFeature` ?
I always get `The local reference frame is not valid! Ab orting description of point with index [...]` and it's annoying. The rest of the code work, I just want to disable the warning.

I've tried searching on the online documentation, but didn't find a way to disable warning.

Is there a way to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Don't assume that everyone know what you are talking about. What is "PCL SHOTEstimation"? Can you provide some context? But yes, most compilers provide a way to suppress warnings - but I would generally advice against it - fixing the cause of the warning is usually a better approach.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I've edited my question to clarify the library I'm using.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I know fixing the cause of the warning is usually a better way, but in this scenario it doesn't matter if I can't get a SHOT descriptor for every keypoints, I will just discard them later in my pipeline